# AWS DMS Task - Reading from source is paused. Total storage used by swap files exceeded the limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I am using AWS DMS to run a migration task full load + cdc. I am migrating a like for like rds mysql database to another rds mysql database.

Its been at 97% for a while now and i can see in the cloudwatch logs a few times the following message.

```
2023-02-01T19:52:57 [SORTER ]I: Reading from source is paused. Total storage used by swap files exceeded the limit 1048576000 bytes (sorter_transaction.c:110)
```

This suggests to me either the **source**, **target** or **replication** instance are using 1gb of swap storage. However when i check cloudwatch that does not seem to be the case.

Whats happening here

**replica instance**

[image]

**target instance**

[image]

**source instance**

[image]

**task settings**

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "EnableLogging": true,
        "EnableLogContext": false,
        "LogComponents": [
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TRANSFORMATION"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "IO"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TARGET_LOAD"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "PERFORMANCE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SORTER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "REST_SERVER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "VALIDATOR_EXT"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TARGET_APPLY"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TASK_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TABLES_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "METADATA_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "FILE_FACTORY"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "COMMON"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "ADDONS"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "DATA_STRUCTURE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "COMMUNICATION"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "FILE_TRANSFER"
            }
        ],
        "CloudWatchLogGroup": "dms-tasks-geeiq-prod-master-replication-instance",
        "CloudWatchLogStream": "dms-task-PLBNPFYKIAWHZDEPAPTDASAD4P6GCIPMRW3ZRXA"
    },
    "StreamBufferSettings": {
        "StreamBufferCount": 3,
        "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5,
        "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8
    },
    "ErrorBehavior": {
        "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": true,
        "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
        "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "RecoverableErrorStopRetryAfterThrottlingMax": true,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
        "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
        "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "EventErrorPolicy": "IGNORE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
        "DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
        "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
        "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
        "TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
        "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE"
    },
    "TTSettings": {
        "TTS3Settings": null,
        "TTRecordSettings": null,
        "EnableTT": false
    },
    "FullLoadSettings": {
        "CommitRate": 10000,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
        "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 8,
        "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
        "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
        "TargetTablePrepMode": "DROP_AND_CREATE"
    },
    "TargetMetadata": {
        "ParallelApplyBufferSize": 0,
        "ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "ParallelApplyThreads": 0,
        "TargetSchema": "",
        "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "SupportLobs": true,
        "LobChunkSize": 64,
        "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false,
        "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
        "LobMaxSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
        "FullLobMode": true,
        "LimitedSizeLobMode": false,
        "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0
    },
    "BeforeImageSettings": null,
    "ControlTablesSettings": {
        "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "StatusTableEnabled": false,
        "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": false,
        "HistoryTableEnabled": false,
        "ControlSchema": "",
        "FullLoadExceptionTableEnabled": false
    },
    "LoopbackPreventionSettings": null,
    "CharacterSetSettings": null,
    "FailTaskWhenCleanTaskResourceFailed": false,
    "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
        "StatementCacheSize": 50,
        "CommitTimeout": 1,
        "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
        "BatchSplitSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
        "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
        "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
        "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
        "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024
    },
    "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
        "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
        "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
        "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
    },
    "PostProcessingRules": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message "Reading from source is paused. Total storage used by swap files exceeded the limit ..." is related to contention on target database to apply changes, so, DMS pause source reading operation to avoid more accumulation of database and have storage full situation. Missing primary keys or indexes could case a full scan operation during UPDATE or DELETE operation causing a performance issues.

You could analyze your target apply latency, review link below to analyze your issue.

[How can I troubleshoot high target latency on an AWS DMS task?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-high-target-latency/)

[What are SWAP files and why are they consuming space on my AWS DMS instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-swap-files-consuming-space/)